# Get all span innerHTML in an array

Tags: javascript, html

So I m trying to understand JS, been doing a little JS project to learn it. Trying to make a simple calculator with javascript/html but got stuck already.

I want to get the innerHTML from all the spans in an array, but I can't figure out how to do it. (I want to use pure JavaScript). What I tried is this:

```
var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var arrayNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= allSpans.length; i++) {
   arrayNumbers.push(allSpans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

And my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <span class="numb">1</span>
    <span class="numb">2</span>
    <span class="numb">3</span>
    <span class="calc">x</span><br />

    <span class="numb">4</span>
    <span class="numb">5</span>
    <span class="numb">6</span>
    <span class="calc">/</span><br />

    <span class="numb">7</span>
    <span class="numb">8</span>
    <span class="numb">9</span>
    <span class="calc">√</span><br />

    <span class="numb">0</span>
    <span class="calc">+</span>
    <span class="calc">-</span>
    <span class="calc">=</span><br />
    <input type="text" >
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the best methode to use and why? Trying to learn it the proper way :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Just replace `i <= allSpans.length` with `i < allSpans.length`.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wjuC/1/).

`Array.length` returns the number of elements in an array. But remember, an array indexing starts from `0` (not just in JS but in most languages). Thus, as in your example, an array of length 16 will only have indexes up to 15. Accessing `array[16]` would crash the code.

To prevent an error like this, you could use jQuery .each (but I suggest you learn standard JS first).

```
var array = [];
$('span').each(function () {
    array.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wjuC/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, just one minor mistake: use `<` instead of `<=` in the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
   arrayNumbers.push(allSpans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

When using array indexes, they go from `0` to `length - 1` (which equals an amount `length` elements), so in your loop you have to make sure you do not exceed this range.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has `<=` in it. `allSpans` has 16 elements (0-15). When you try to access the 16th element, it is `undefined`; `undefined.innerHTML` throws an error; and your code stops.

Solution: Replace `<=` with `<`.

Also: In this particular case it doesn't matter, but if you had a button `>` or `&`, you would get bad results. I suggest using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` here.

Comment: +1, textContent is much more appropiate than innerHTML in this case.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var arrayNumbers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
       arrayNumbers.push(allSpans.item(i).innerHTML);
    }
```

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of an elements's child elements with the specified tagname, as a NodeList object.

REFERENCE

https://studio.tellme.com/dom/ref/methods/getelementsbytagname.html

Answer (score 1):

some weeks ago i wrote a very simple calculator using a similar approach as you...

it works on mobile devices and modern browsers.

here is the css

```
body,html{
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:#666;
}
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.clc{
 width:256px;
 height:320px;
 clear:both;
}
.clc>*{
 border:4px solid #666;
 border-radius:4px;
 font:normal normal bold 20px/56px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 border-radius:10px;
}
.clc>input{
 width:100%;
 height:20%;
 text-align:right;
 padding:0 20px;
}
.clc>div{
 width:25%;
 height:20%;
 background-color:#5a5a5a;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 float:left;
}
.clc>div:nth-child(4n+1){
 background-color:#f36573;
}
.clc>div:nth-last-child(1){
 width:100%;
 background-color:#ffb343;
}
```

here is the very short javascript code that does the work for you

```
function calc(e){
 var a=e.target.innerText,b=this.firstChild;
 b.value=a=='='?eval(b.value):a=='C'?'':b.value+a;
}
var gui=document.createElement('div');
gui.className='clc';
gui.innerHTML='<input><div>'+('789+456-123*C0./='.split('').join('</div><div>'))+'</div>';
gui.addEventListener('click',calc,false);

window.onload=function(){
 document.body.appendChild(gui);
}
```

and here is a live example

http://jsfiddle.net/trjsJ/

if you don't understand something just ask!

**UPDATE**

**calc explained**

```
function calc(event){
 var clickedText=event.target.innerText,// this is the clicked element inner Text
 inputBox=this.firstChild; // this is the input box
 if(clickedText=='='){// if the clicked text is equal symbol
  inputBox.value=eval(inputBox.value); // calculate the input string by evulating it
 }else{
  if(clickedText=='C'){ // if clicked text is C 
   inputBox.value='';// clear the input box
  }else{
   inputBox.value=inputBox.value+clickedText; // add the clicked text
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that javascript code looks beautiful! Can you say how the function calc(e) works? the last sentence isn't really clear to me

Comment: added a description of the calcfunction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to store the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of your [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements in an array:

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var span_array = [].map.call(span, function (element) {
  return element.innerHTML;
});
```

You can optimize this procedure with ECMAScript 6 (ES6):

```
const span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
let span_array = Array.from(span, element => element.innerHTML);
```

---

> **Note:** I would personally recommend using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) in conjunction with the [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function rather than [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) if you are trying to access non-HTML content inside of your tags.